# initState function not running on screen rendering - flutter

Tags: flutter

It seems initstate not working on screen render I am not sure why. I also ran print statement under initState and it prints nothing. It always grabs the empty variable of left/rightNewsinfo or left/rightTitle because it gives "`Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///`" error everytime I run it. I installed `SimpleLinkPreview` function from pub.dev and it gives correct print statement. I think error is coming from my code. I am new on flutter. Null safety is enabled

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:news_upload/widgets/news_box.dart';
import 'package:simple_link_preview/simple_link_preview.dart';

class ActualNews extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/actualNews';

  static List<dynamic> leftNewsInfo = [];
  static List<dynamic> rightNewsInfo = [];

  @override
  State<ActualNews> createState() => _ActualNewsState();
}

class _ActualNewsState extends State<ActualNews> {
  final leftNewsLink =
      "https://www.ndtv.com/india-news/goa-congress-requests-speaker-to-disqualify-mlas-michael-lobo-digambar-kamat-after-accusing-them-of-planning-defections-3146905";

  var rightNewsLink =
      "https://zeenews.india.com/india/kaali-poster-row-tmc-mp-insults-maa-kali-but-mamata-banerjee-smriti-irani-lashes-out-at-mahua-moitra-2484047.html";

  String leftTitle = '';

  String leftImage = '';

  String rightTitle = '';

  String rightImage = '';

  Future<void> getNews(lInfo, rInfo) async {
    var L = await SimpleLinkPreview.getPreview(leftNewsLink);
    var R = await SimpleLinkPreview.getPreview(rightNewsLink);
    leftTitle = L!.title!;
    leftImage = L.image!;
    rightTitle = R!.title!;
    rightImage = R.image!;
    lInfo = [leftTitle, leftImage];
    rInfo = [rightTitle, rightImage];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0), () {
      getNews(ActualNews.leftNewsInfo, ActualNews.rightNewsInfo);
      print(ActualNews.leftNewsInfo[0]);
      print("hello world");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      children: <Widget>[
        NewsBox(ActualNews.leftNewsInfo, ActualNews.rightNewsInfo),
        IconButton(
          icon: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using Future.delay but giving no time. You are setting 0 seconds. By this time the getNews is still not fetched!!

Comment: no this is not the problem, it immediately throws the error `Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///`. but just to be sure I tried giving it 5 seconds then 10 seconds, still got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`setState`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) to change the internal state of `_ActualNewsState`. Actually, the internal state should be changed only by `setState`.

I'd also fix both statics `leftNewsInfo` and `rightNewsInfo` by moving them to a non-static in the `_ActualNewsState` class and remove the parameters of `getNews`. This is prone to error as static class vars are shared between multiple instances of `ActualNews` widget.

To fix it just do the following:

```dart
  Future<void> getNews() async {
    var L = await SimpleLinkPreview.getPreview(leftNewsLink);
    var R = await SimpleLinkPreview.getPreview(rightNewsLink);
    setState(() {
      leftTitle = L!.title!;
      leftImage = L.image!;
      rightTitle = R!.title!;
      rightImage = R.image!;

      leftNewsInfo = [leftTitle, leftImage];
      rightNewsInfo = [rightTitle, leftImage];
    });
  }
```

Comment: I want to use `leftNewsInfo` and `rightNewsInfo` outside the function to send them to another widget `newsBox` how would I do that ?

Comment: I tried your method, I put `leftNewsInfo` and `rightNewsInfo` as `ActualNews.leftNewsInfo` and `ActualNews.rightNewsInfo` because it couldn't recognize it. I removed parameters from getNews(). debugger immediately throws "`Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:/// `" error, no change.

Comment: To use `leftNewsInfo` and `rightNewsInfo`in another widget the best approach is to use a shared state between them. Take a look [here for an example](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) on how to use [`provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: This error, `Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:/// `, seems unrelated to the changes.